# Drop multiple databases with names matching a pattern

Tags: mysql

I want to drop all the databases starting with a word.

```
abc
xyz
cms_db1
cms_db2
cms_xyz
pqr
```

In the example given above, I will like to drop all the Databases starting with the word "cms".
I guess maatkit or shell script can do it. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linux way:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_STARTS_WITH="cms"
MUSER="root"
MPWD="yourpass"
MYSQL="mysql"

DBS="$($MYSQL -u$MUSER -p$MPWD -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS; do

if [[ "$db" =~ "^${DB_STARTS_WITH}" ]]; then
    echo "Deleting $db"
    $MYSQL -u$MUSER -p$MPWD -Bse "drop database $db"
fi

done
```

Of course use the `drop` part at your own risk ;)

Comment: Worked for me, but needed `drop database $db` since `drop $db` caused a syntax error

Comment: This just silently fails for me.

Comment: Silently fails for me too. It finds the databases, but doesn't execute the regex. [@swaley's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14874352/736809) works great.

Comment: SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'prefix%'; is much more reliable

Comment: @cloakedninjas has a better all-in-mysql solution.

Answer (score 89):

Here's a pure mySQL solution in two queries:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP DATABASE `', SCHEMA_NAME, '`;')
FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'cms_%';
```

Then copy and paste the resulting recordset and run

Comment: You can use the `-s` (`--silent`) flag to `mysql` to remove the grid around the result, making copying and pasting easier.

Comment: Very nice. I like that this solutaion is not “fire this dynamic drop query”, it’s “dynamically generate the static drop queries and then run them on your own”. It gives you a chance to double check everything before pulling the trigger.

Comment: I would like to integrate the `--silent` thing in the answer but the edit queue is full, as usual to me...

Answer (score 18):

I had to improve neurinos script because of special chars in my password, missing 'drop DATABASE ...' and not working comparision for DB_STARTS_WITH expression. The following script did work on Ubuntu Server:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_STARTS_WITH="grp"
MUSER="root"
MPWD="YOUR_PASSWORD"
MYSQL="mysql"

DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -p"$MPWD" -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS; do

if [[ "$db" == $DB_STARTS_WITH* ]]; then
    echo "Deleting $db"
    $MYSQL -u $MUSER -p"$MPWD" -Bse "drop database $db"
fi

done
```

Comment: Sorry, long time ago and I do not know anymore... why?

Comment: Any suggestion for db names with hyphens in them? I get syntax errors with and without backticks.

Comment: To answer my own question, the backticks need to be escaped.

Comment: Is there any way to speed this up? We have over 5,000 databases and connecting running drop and closing for each takes forever.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. Only thought is to parallelise it in any kind of way...

Answer (score 10):

I would use something like:

```
echo "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'cms_%'" \
  | mysql \
  | tail -n +2 \
  | xargs -n1 mysqladmin -f drop
```

If you don't have your default username and password configured inside `~/my.cnf`, you may need to supply the username and password via the `-u` and `-p` switches to the mysql/mysqladmin commands above.

(Edit - added -n arg to tail.)

Comment: Please stop using tail or head to skip header, use mysql -N instead :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Linux way:

```
for db_name in $(mysql -u USER -pPASS -e "show databases like 'cms_%'" -ss)
do
     mysql -u USER -pPASS -e "drop database ${db_name}";
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to stay completely within MySQL/MariaDB (i.e. without using bash scripts and such) you can do the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE clean()
BEGIN
    SET @query := (SELECT CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ', SCHEMA_NAME, ';') FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'dbtVDB%' LIMIT 1);
    WHILE @query != '' DO
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        SET @query := (SELECT CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ', SCHEMA_NAME, ';') FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'cms%' LIMIT 1);
    END WHILE;
    DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE mysql.db.Db LIKE 'cms%';
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
CALL clean();
DROP PROCEDURE clean;
```

Comment: DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE mysql.db.Db LIKE 'cms%'; is unrelated

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer suggesting a "for" loop from the shell.  In my case, I had subdirectory names matching my database names so I made arrays, then used them in the command.

(I could have done this using the mysql data directory come to think of it, even if I hadn't had the setup I had. On my bitnami VM this is 
/opt/bitnami/mysql/data.)

1. created array from subset of files:  tbtdirs=(tbt*2015*)
2. Tested a potentially spooky command first w/ "echo": for d in ${tbtdirs[@]}; do echo mysql -pPASS -e "drop database $d"; done
3. dropped all databases in the array:  for d in ${tbtdirs[@]}; do  mysql -pPASS -e "drop database $d"; done

Worked like a charm! Also modified the loop to remove subdirectories. I used Linux command line for quite some time before learning how useful the bash commands could be.

Answer (score 0):

Using @léo-alves-de-araujo I have modified it to ask the user/password (More secure way) from command line (with linux)

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo -n "Enter Mysql User:"
read user
echo -n "Enter Mysql Password:"
read -s password
for db_name in $(mysql -u $user --password=$password -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'cms_%'" -ss 2>/dev/null)
do
        mysql -u $user --password=$password -e "DROP DATABASE ${db_name}" 2>/dev/null;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved @neurino solution to avoid storing of MySQL credentials in the script and passing them through a command line (it might be visible in the list of processes then)

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_STARTS_WITH="cms"
MYSQL="mysql"

read -p "Enter MySQL user name: " MYSQL_USER
read -s -p "Enter password: " MYSQL_PASSWORD

CREDENTIALS_FILE="$(mktemp)"
chmod 600 $CREDENTIALS_FILE
cat > $CREDENTIALS_FILE <<- EOM
[client]
user=$MYSQL_USER
password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
EOM

trap "{ rm -f $CREDENTIALS_FILE; }" EXIT

DATABASES="$(echo "show databases;" | $MYSQL --defaults-file=$CREDENTIALS_FILE)"

for DATABASE in $DATABASES; do
    if [[ $DATABASE =~ ^${DB_STARTS_WITH} ]]; then
        echo Removing $DATABASE...
        echo "drop database $DATABASE" | $MYSQL --defaults-file=$CREDENTIALS_FILE
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvising on the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23886144/2469308) by *@cloakedninjas*, for easier retrieval of all the queries to execute in a single string.

Firstly, you can set the maximum value for [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to the maximum possible value, for this particular session:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

Now, you can prepare a query string (to execute later) using SQL. Using `information_schema`, we can get name of all the databases matching the pattern. Now, use `Concat()` to prepare a single `DROP DATABASE ..` query, and then utilize `Group_Concat()` to merge them all into a single string, for easier retrieval.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DROP DATABASE `', SCHEMA_NAME, '`;') 
                    SEPARATOR ' ') AS query_to_execute
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'cms_%'
```

Now copy the string in `query_to_execute` and run it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Option for SQL Server (T-SQL):

```
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @command = @command + 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + CHAR(13)
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE 'cms\_%' {escape '\'};

PRINT @command

-- Double check generated command and then uncomment
-- EXEC sp_executesql @command;
```